# Disable prompt when sending an SMS that "may cause malicious charges"

Tags: sms, lenovo

Since I got my new phone Lenovo S960, I have a problem when sending an SMS. If I send an SMS to any numbers, it prompts me this message:

> Try to send to 0784xxxxxx a sms may cause malicious charges, are you sure to send the sms?

I tried with several messaging apps, but they still give me this prompt message, and it bothers me because everytime I have to tap OK, but sometimes I forget and the message is not sent.

Comment: Do all your numbers have a 0 prefixed?

Comment: the romanian prefix is 40, so some of them start with +40..but the numbers are saved in the phone strating with 07xxxxx. its like the app sees them like foreign numbers and it is charging roaming fees

Comment: When you send an SMS with correct country code, does the message appear too? If it doesn't, then as a "dirty" (but recommended) workaround is to add the country code to all numbers (this is useful if you make a call/send SMS from other country). However, this question is still valid, and someone might know if it's possible to disable it.

Comment: On the other hand, is it possible that this is related to [SECUREit](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht101304) on Lenovo S960?

Comment: I have uninstaled secureit, i have root so i removed it..should i flash a new rom ?